# WCF, custom authorization with data being passed to service class

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security

I wrote a UserNamePasswordValidator descendant for validation purpose (basicHttpBinding).

The problem is when I validate a user against back service I receive its identifier that I have to use in service class method. That turns out to be a huge problem... unless you know how to do it ...

Is there another authorization alternative that I will not have to pass userName / password in method header or even worse in method's parameters of the Service?

Answer (score 0):

WCF service authentication and authorization can use UserNamePasswordValidator and IAuthorizationPolicy. Here's an [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/698862/Custom-Authentication-and-Authorization-in-WCF) on how to do it. If not, try using [IPrincipal](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33872/Custom-Authorization-in-WCF).

Comment: I am only wondering how can I pass some additional data from my custom validator to my CustomPrincipal ...

Comment: You can define a new class derived from X509CertificateValidator and implement the abstract Validate method,where you can pass some data and use your logic to handle with it.You can check out [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/how-to-create-a-service-that-employs-a-custom-certificate-validator) for specific examples.

Comment: well all those methods implies certificate usage ... Can not we do anything without securing the channel?